# Where do I put coding logic in my React Application

Tags: model-view-controller, reactjs

So I have made a simple Json search application that you can view on codepen. It searches the Json title and tags and returns any matches:
http://codepen.io/ghozt12/pen/LVaxLM

It is based off of the example given on the React website (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

However I do not understand where to put the logic that filters the search results. If React is just the V in MVC, shouldn't the business logic go in the Model? But React is just the view, so where do you put the logic?

Specifically for my application, I placed the search code in this react class and I wanted to know if this was the correct place to put it? (see my codepen for detailed view).

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

    // CODE THAT FILTERS SEARCH RESULTS GOES HERE
    // creates rowTitle array

   return ( 
         <div> 
           {rowsTitle} 
         </div>
       );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you're going to get a lot of different answers as this problem can be tackled several ways. If it were me, i'd isolate the filter logic into a separate library and require that library. Otherwise if this logic is actually reusable and has React renders stuff I'd just make it a mixin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you said, React is just the V in the MVC. So, where do you put your business logic?

For small, view-specific business logic, it's ok to put that on the component, as you did. If the business logic is in the component, it's going to be on an event-handler, in the render or any other component method.

If you have non-view-specific business logic, and it runs on the client (or both on the client and server), it's always a good practice to isolate that on a separate JavaScript module. React does not play nice with AMD, so you are better off not using RequireJS for modularization. You should probably use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). In this case, all you would have to do is add this to the top or your component file: `var myBusinessLogic = require('./myBusinessLogic')`. Now you can delegate processing to this module. This is the prefered way, because JavaScript modules are easily testable using Jest, Jasmine, Karma or Mocha.

There's also a third scenario in which you delegate business logic to the server. You can directly make Ajax calls to the API on the server, to do this processing, or you can go with the more sophisticated way and use Flux. There's a plethora of Flux implementations out there, like Alt, Redux and Fluxxor. I prefer to have my own implementation of Flux using the default Dispatcher. Within the `ActionCreators` I call a method on the `clientApi` (a JS module), which does an Ajax call using [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to the server. This call is handled by an Express route which finally delegates the business logic to the `serverApi`.

**EDIT**: I just moved to Redux :)

Comment: Is there any reason you stick to Facebook Flux than going with Redux?

Comment: @user636525 This was a long time ago. I just moved to Redux :)

Comment: Thanks ! Looks like we are also moving towards Redux, although Alt looks so easy :)

Answer (score 6):

I know this answer is late but wanted to add my thoughts. Usually you want to keep presentation components dumb. Meaning your UI components have no logic other then something like a type which may style the component differently. It’s a good idea to pull your logic out into react hooks then using the react hooks in your controlling component. That way all the logic is in your hooks and not in your presentational components making them a lot more independent and reusable.

Comment: I think this is a great addition covering the new functional paradigm. It would be worth expanding your answer with more explanation and an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can push logic inside every class Component and the App Component. Logic in class Component for this state  and Logic in App Component for all Application